# Class 'Spatie\Analytics\AnalyticsServiceProvider' not found

Tags: php, google-analytics, laravel-5.4

This is duplicate question, I am trying to use spatie/laravel-analytics but in localhost it does not throw this error but on server it shows this error, I'm using shared hosting. Also I've tried other solutions. My versions are:

Laravel 5.4
Analytics 3
PHP 7.1.5

Error :

> Class 'Spatie\Analytics\AnalyticsServiceProvider' not found

Comment: Are you using Composer ? If so, you should not be able to use it in the shared hosting, right ? I think you are missing `composer update`.

Comment: Nope, I'm not using composer, I've manually uploaded all files with others packages like youtube, socialite. Then today I just uploaded the package under the vendor file, is that casing the problem ?

Comment: I don't know how are you autoloading that, could you explain that please ?

Comment: I've uploaded all files to public_html files then configured and move index.php and all public file to root!

Comment: But laravel process in `public` folder, not root, why are you moving it ?

Comment: sorry i mean to public_html folder not root! 
this is the snapshot of directory(http://imgur.com/a/MjN80)

Answer (score 0):

I've deleted and re-uploaded all files, it does not show this error now!